# Identifying two integers that add up to a specific target in linear time

Tags: for-loop, go

i write a golang code to find two numbers that produce specific target number. I write the code using two for loops. Here is the code:

```
func FindTwoNumbers(arr []int, target int) {
    for i := 0; i < len(arr); i++ {
        for j := 0; j < len(arr); j++ {
            if arr[i] == arr[j] {
                continue
            }
            if arr[i]+arr[j] == target {
                fmt.Printf("Numbers: %v and %v\n", arr[i], arr[j])
                arr = append(arr[:i], arr[i+1:]...)
                i--
            }

        }

    }
}

func main() {
    FindTwoNumbers([]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, 14)
}
```

Here is the output:

```
go run main.go
Numbers: 5 and 9
Numbers: 6 and 8
```

Is there another way to write the code like maybe have less loop but produces the same result ?

Answer (score 0):

Build a map that records how many times each value appears in the input slice; you can build such a map in linear time (wrt to the length of the input slice). Then, you can iterate over the resulting map, again in linear time, in order to find the two ints of interest (if any).

Here is a simple implementation (caveat: it doesn't check for integer underflow/overflow):

```golang
func FindTwoNumbers(ns []int, target int) (int, int, bool) {
    sizeHint := len(ns) // optimises for cases where all elements are distinct
    m := make(map[int]int, sizeHint)
    for _, n := range ns {
        m[n]++
    }
    for k, count := range m {
        diff := target - k
        if _, found := m[diff]; !found || diff == k && count < 2 {
            continue
        }
        return k, diff, true
    }
    return 0, 0, false
}

func main() {
    ns := []int{7, 8, 3, 4, 10}
    fmt.Println(FindTwoNumbers(ns, 14))
    fmt.Println(FindTwoNumbers(ns, 9))
}
```

([Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/ijsrWmTJ4L_E))

Output:

```
4 10 true
0 0 false
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops. It looks like after I petitioned to re-open, I walked away and everyone else filled in an answer.  For what it's worth:

```
func FindTwoNumbers(arr []int, target int) {

    table := make(map[int]int)

    // keep a map that maps each integer in the array to its number of occurrences
    for i := 0; i < len(arr); i++ {
        table[arr[i]]++
    }

    // for each unique key, figure out what value it needs to be paired with
    // and check to see if that key is also in the map
    for key, _ := range table {
        var needed int = 1
        var match int = target - key
        if match == key {
            needed = 2 // if target is "6", then "3" needs to appear at least twice in the list
        }
        if key > match {
            continue // avoid reporting duplicate pairs by skipping when key>match
        }

        if table[match] >= needed {
            fmt.Printf("Numbers: %v and %v\n", key, match)
        }
    }
}
```

The above solution has a runtime of `O(N)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the start of second iteration with
`j:= i + 1`
so you dont have to check`if arr[i] == arr[j]` to continue.